# $_can not output what I want

Tags: perl

I am using $_ to read data from my formatted response file into a file named response;parts of my `perl` code is like this: I am sure that `$rname` can be found in my file such as:`RESP.IU.BILL.00.BH2`is one of the `$rname`
file,so do not bother to think the file can't be found.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$high_pass_co = 0.002;
$low_pass_co = 1;
$du = 120;
$pre_ev = 20;
$sample = 1.0;


open RES, ">response";

    $rname= "RESP." . $ev;

# make response file
    open (IRIS, "<$rname");
    while (<IRIS>)   {
                print "$rname \n you are processing:\n";  
        chop;
                print "\n $_\n\n";
        if ($_ =~ /Start date:/ ) {
            $firis=0;$fprint=0;
            $Yst=substr($_,25,4);
            $Dst=substr($_,30,3);
            if ($year > $Yst) {
                $firis++;
            }
            if ($year == $Yst && $day >= $Dst) {
                $firis++;
            }
        }
        if ($_ =~ /End date:/ ) {
            if ($_ =~ /No Ending Time/) {
                $Yen=`date +%Y`;
                chop($Yen);
                $Den=365;
                if ($year < $Yen) {
                    $firis++;
                }
                if ($year == $Yen && $day <= $Den) {
                    $firis++;
                }
            } else {
                $Yen=substr($_,25,4);
                $Den=substr($_,30,3);
                if ($year < $Yen ) {
                    $firis++;
                }
                if ($year == $Yen && $day <= $Den) {
                    $firis++;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($_ =~ /B053F05/ ) {$UNI=substr($_,51,25);}
        if ($_ =~ /B053F07/ ) {$A0=substr($_,51,25);}
        if ($_ =~ /B053F09/ ) {$NZ=substr($_,51,5);}
        if ($_ =~ /B053F04/ ) {
            $Sn=substr($_,51,5);
        }
        if ($_ =~ /B053F14/ ) {
            $NP=substr($_,51,5);
            $fprint = 1;
            if($firis == 2 && $Sn == 1) {
                if($UNI =~ /Displacement/) {$id="0";}
                if($UNI =~ /Velocity/) {$id="1";}
                if($UNI =~ /Acceleration/) {$id="2";}
                print RES "$sname\n";
                print RES " A0 normalization factor: $A0\n";
                print RES " Number of zeroes:            $NZ\n";
                print RES " Number of poles:              $NP\n";
            }
        }
        if ($_ =~ /B053F10-13/ && $firis == 2 && $fprint == 1 && $Sn == 1) {
            $tmp = substr($_,11,70);
            print RES "$tmp\n";
        }
        if ($_ =~ /B053F15-18/ && $firis == 2 && $fprint == 1 && $Sn == 1) {
            $tmp = substr($_,11,70);
            print RES "$tmp\n";
        }
        if ($_ =~ /Sensitivity/ && $_ =~ /B058F04/) {
            $SE=substr($_,51,15);
            if($firis == 2) {
                print RES " Sensitivity:             $SE\n";
            }
        }   
    }
    close(IRIS);
 close(RES);
```

and my formated waited to be read file is below:

```
#       << IRIS SEED Reader, Release 5.2 >>
#       
#       ======== CHANNEL RESPONSE DATA ========
B050F03     Station:     TIXI
B050F16     Network:     IU
B052F03     Location:    00
B052F04     Channel:     BH1
B052F22     Start date:  2014,264,00:00:00
B052F23     End date:    2599,365,23:59:59
#       =======================================
#       +               +--------------------------------------------+                +
#       +               |   Response (Poles & Zeros),  TIXI ch BH1   |                +
#       +               +--------------------------------------------+                +
#       
B053F03     Transfer function type:                A [Laplace Transform (Rad/sec)]
B053F04     Stage sequence number:                 1
B053F05     Response in units lookup:              M/S - Velocity in Meters Per Second
B053F06     Response out units lookup:             V - Volts
B053F07     A0 normalization factor:               3948.58
B053F08     Normalization frequency:               0.02
B053F09     Number of zeroes:                      2
B053F14     Number of poles:                       4
#       Complex zeroes:
#         i  real          imag          real_error    imag_error
B053F10-13    0  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
B053F10-13    1  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
#       Complex poles:
#         i  real          imag          real_error    imag_error
B053F15-18    0 -1.234000E-02  1.234000E-02  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
B053F15-18    1 -1.234000E-02 -1.234000E-02  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
B053F15-18    2 -3.918000E+01  4.912000E+01  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
B053F15-18    3 -3.918000E+01 -4.912000E+01  0.000000E+00  0.000000E+00
#       
#       +                  +---------------------------------------+                  +
#       +                  |       Channel Gain,  TIXI ch BH1      |                  +
#       +                  +---------------------------------------+                  +
#       
B058F03     Stage sequence number:                 1
B058F04     Gain:                                  2.276000E+03
B058F05     Frequency of gain:                     5.000000E-02 HZ
B058F06     Number of calibrations:                0
#       
#       +               +-------------------------------------------+                 +
#       +               |   Response (Coefficients),  TIXI ch BH1   |                 +
#       +               +-------------------------------------------+                 +
#       
B054F03     Transfer function type:                D
B054F04     Stage sequence number:                 2
B054F05     Response in units lookup:              V - Volts
B054F06     Response out units lookup:             COUNTS - Digital Counts
B054F07     Number of numerators:                  0
B054F10     Number of denominators:                0
#       
#       +                      +------------------------------+                       +
#       +                      |   Decimation,  TIXI ch BH1   |                       +
#       +                      +------------------------------+                       +
#       
B057F03     Stage sequence number:                 2
B057F04     Input sample rate:                     2.000000E+01
B057F05     Decimation factor:                     1
B057F06     Decimation offset:                     0
B057F07     Estimated delay (seconds):             0.000000E+00
B057F08     Correction applied (seconds):          0.000000E+00
#       
#       +                  +---------------------------------------+                  +
#       +                  |       Channel Gain,  TIXI ch BH1      |                  +
#       +                  +---------------------------------------+                  +
#       
B058F03     Stage sequence number:                 2
B058F04     Gain:                                  1.677720E+06
B058F05     Frequency of gain:                     0.000000E+00 HZ
B058F06     Number of calibrations:                0
#       
#       +               +-------------------------------------------+                 +
#       +               |   Response (Coefficients),  TIXI ch BH1   |                 +
#       +               +-------------------------------------------+                 +
#       
B054F03     Transfer function type:                D
B054F04     Stage sequence number:                 3
B054F05     Response in units lookup:              COUNTS - Digital Counts
B054F06     Response out units lookup:             COUNTS - Digital Counts
B054F07     Number of numerators:                  67
B054F10     Number of denominators:                0
#       Numerator coefficients:
#         i, coefficient,  error
B054F08-09    0 -3.653420E-17  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09    1  3.674880E-08  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09    2 -4.270600E-07  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09    3  1.145020E-06  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09    4 -1.875940E-07  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09    5 -3.372740E-07  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09    6  2.787470E-06  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09    7 -3.744030E-06  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09    8  5.411720E-06  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09    9  7.473360E-06  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   10 -5.177590E-04  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   11  2.106770E-04  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   12  4.632580E-05  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   13 -6.082220E-04  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   14  1.441750E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   15 -2.406270E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   16  3.225340E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   17 -3.506390E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   18  2.814410E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   19 -7.719710E-04  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   20 -2.805120E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   21  7.778050E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   22 -1.358150E-02  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   23  1.917650E-02  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   24 -2.297040E-02  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   25  2.403980E-02  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   26 -2.209860E-02  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   27  8.607340E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   28  1.175250E-02  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   29 -4.477870E-02  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   30  9.649230E-02  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   31 -1.917550E-01  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   32  5.276520E-01  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   33  7.241670E-01  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   34 -1.569050E-01  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   35  4.425740E-02  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   36  3.141680E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   37 -2.667140E-02  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   38  3.615320E-02  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   39 -3.856870E-02  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   40  3.108420E-02  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   41 -2.352590E-02  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   42  1.532110E-02  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   43 -7.403980E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   44  1.096450E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   45  3.097970E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   46 -5.193200E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   47  5.561310E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   48 -4.761100E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   49  3.382130E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   50 -1.920520E-03  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   51  7.152180E-04  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   52  7.677190E-05  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   53 -4.518970E-04  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   54  5.027000E-04  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   55 -5.650370E-04  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   56 -5.568000E-05  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   57  1.577360E-05  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   58 -1.419850E-06  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   59  8.149090E-07  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   60  6.807950E-07  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   61 -1.252730E-06  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   62  1.524350E-06  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   63 -2.833360E-07  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   64 -1.063840E-08  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   65  1.257120E-09  0.000000E+00
B054F08-09   66 -5.429540E-11  0.000000E+00
#       
#       +                      +------------------------------+                       +
#       +                      |   Decimation,  TIXI ch BH1   |                       +
#       +                      +------------------------------+                       +
#       
B057F03     Stage sequence number:                 3
B057F04     Input sample rate:                     2.000000E+01
B057F05     Decimation factor:                     1
B057F06     Decimation offset:                     0
B057F07     Estimated delay (seconds):             1.630500E+00
B057F08     Correction applied (seconds):          1.630500E+00
#       
#       +                  +---------------------------------------+                  +
#       +                  |       Channel Gain,  TIXI ch BH1      |                  +
#       +                  +---------------------------------------+                  +
#       
B058F03     Stage sequence number:                 3
B058F04     Gain:                                  1.000000E+00
B058F05     Frequency of gain:                     0.000000E+00 HZ
B058F06     Number of calibrations:                0
#       
#       +                  +---------------------------------------+                  +
#       +                  |   Channel Sensitivity,  TIXI ch BH1   |                  +
#       +                  +---------------------------------------+                  +
#
```

but my output file is empty,Where  is wrong about my code?

Comment: This is pretty straightward debugging. When you reach the line where you expect `$_ =~ /B053F10-13/ && $firis == 2 && $fprint == 1 && $Sn == 1` to be true, why isn't it? Specifically, which variable is different than expected? Now, find out why that variable is different than expected using the same process.

Comment: Note that no line in your input file contains both `Sensitivity` and `B058F04`, so `$_ =~ /Sensitivity/ && $_ =~ /B058F04/` will never be true.

Comment: Tip: `$_ =~ /.../` can be shortened to `/.../`.

Comment: You are writing Perl 4 code. Upgrade the code to Perl 5 and you'll get much better error checking (e.g. use `use strict; use warnings;`)

Answer (score 4):

> I am sure that `$rname` can be found in my file such as:`RESP.IU.BILL.00.BH2`is one of the `$rname` file,so do not bother to think the file can't be found.

If you say that `RESP.IU.BILL.00.BH2` exists on your filesystem, then I believe you. But I don't think you're looking for that file.

This is the line which opens your input file:

```
open (IRIS, "<$rname");
```

And this is where you declare the variable `$rname`:

```
$rname= "RESP." . $ev;
```

But you don't declare the variable `$ev` anywhere. So your program is looking for a file called `RESP.` - with an empty extension. I'm guessing that this file doesn't exist, so your call to `open()` is failing silently and your `while (<IRIS>)` loop never gets executed.

A few suggestions that would have caught this problem.

- Adding `use strict` to your code would have thrown an error when you tried to use a variable that you hadn't declared. Of course, it would also mean that you now need to declare all of your variables. This is a very good idea.
- Checking the results of your call to `open()` is always a good idea

  ```
  open (IRIS, "<$rname")
    or die "Couldn't open $rname: $!";
  ```
- Adding `use warnings` to your code would have given you a warning when you tried to read from `IRIS` (as you're attempting to read from a filehandle that wasn't opened successfully).

A few more suggestions.

- These days, we use the three-arg version of `open()` and lexical variables as filehandles.

  ```
  open my $iris_fh, '<', $rname or die(...);
  ```
- If you're reading a file and writing another, then it's often a good idea to write it as a "Unix filter" - you read from STDIN and write to STDOUT. That makes your program more flexible (it can be chained together with other programs) and it's actually easier to write.
- `chomp()` is generally safer than `chop()`.
- Please pay more attention to the indentation of your code. Indentation is supposed to make code easier to understand.
- If you're matching against `$_`, then you can just write `/.../` instead of `$_ =~ /.../`.

Comment: I am not quite understanding " the three-arg version of open() and lexical variables as filehandles".Is it more flexible? If I use "my $iris_fh"you mentioned above then What should I change about my "while (<IRIS>)",can you teach me?@PerlDuck

Comment: If you use a lexical filehandle called `$iris_fh` then you should change the `while` loop to `while (<$iris_fh>) { ... }`. Three-arg `open()` is safer when it comes to filename with obscure characters in. And lexical filehandles are easier to pass around and close themselves automatically when the variable goes out of scope. But none of this is really important - you need to address the main problem (`$ev`) first.

Answer (score 3):

Not only `$ev` but also `$year` and `$day` are undefined. You are also mixing up whether `$year`, `$Yst`, and `$Yen` are from the file or the current date. This isn't going to work

You must start by adding `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` to the top of your program and declaring all of your variables with `my`. That will give you a much better chance of getting it working

Comment: Yes. I missed all of that. When I saw the problem at the outer level, I stopped digging into the detail of the code. But you're absolutely right.